# Import files into python program directly from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have simple question in regards to running Python and some text files it needs.
I have small program which I am supposed to run in the following fashion directly from command line:

```
python3 numbers.py training-images.txt training-labels.txt validation-images.txt > result.txt
```

The way I originally wrote it is that in my code there are names of these files already so I could just run numbers.py . But this is not correct. The correct way is to run the whole thing as above and make sure that numbers.py imports files which are written in command line. How do I write code to import files with names give in command line?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "command line input"

For this you can use "sys" module in Python

> import sys

now, you can use the command line arguments using

> sys.argv

which is a list of all the arguments

Look at the below given example

```
$ python prog.py a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

> sys.argv = ['prog.py', 'a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']

Now you can access the arguments by passing index to sys.argv

eg. sys.argv[0] will return 'prog.py'

Comment: What if I don't know which will be names of the files?

Comment: Do you want to ask the user the file names during the execution of the program?

Comment: Not specifically to insert input. What I am saying that, if you look in my code above, first entry "training-images.txt" doesn't necessarily need to be called that way. It can be called only "images.txt". Or something else. So if I just write my code with sys.argv[1] it will take whatever user input is for index [1]?

Comment: Yeah. That's it. That is why I changed the name in my example, so it would be more clear.